# My motorola 5g stylus updated and the keyboard for logging in is gone

Tags: keyboard, data-recovery, bootloader, locked-out

My information is as follows. My keyboard is the default keyboard. I disabled gboard. The update was last night. I was not logged in when I clicked update, (it was a security update, I turned it on from sleep mode.)

My phone can't open with fingerprint after a restart and the keyboard does not appear. I can receive calls and turn internet on and off.

I did a recovery boot but no luck.
I have been digging for answer and the majority of people say to just do a factory reset but I found 2 cases where the phone just started working again.
I want to know if there is a fix or should I just pray to the Omnissiah?

Comment: Connect an USB keyboard or mouse and reactivate a on-screen keyboard.